# Localization for custom button in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, localization, tinymce

I added a button to TinyMCE with this:

```
editor.addButton('x', {
    title : 'do stuff',
    onclick : function() {
    }
});
```

In setup function. It works well. But I need to localize the title. How can I do it (most simple way)?

Comment: how many languages do you want to use here?

Comment: Well, the most simple way is probably add a function or map with lang parameter (and key, if I need more than that button) to my script which returns me the translation.

Comment: Or just use a placeholder for serverside script.

Comment: hmm, i think you can access the languagefiles directly, but i cannot find the location. are you using an own plugin already, where you could put your new language definitions?

Comment: well, the idea was not to make a plugin. It works just adding this to setup function.

Comment: it might have been that you had an own plugin already in use. would have made things simple then